name 'ONNXMiniLM_L6_V2' is not defined, chromadb embedding not defined with pyinstaller
I'm creating an executable for my python AI project.
So I'm using pyinstaller, but when I launch it, i get the error:
failed to execute ... : name 'ONNXMiniLM_L6_V2' is not defined 

the precise log are this :
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
   File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 384, in exec_module
   File "chromadb\api\models\CollectionCommon.py", line 100, in <module>
   File "chromadb\api\models\CollectionCommon.py", line 112, in CollectionCommon
   File "chromadb\utils\embedding_functions\__init__.py", line 57, in DefaultEmbeddingFunction
 NameError: name 'ONNXMiniLM_L6_V2' is not defined

i tried

check dependency
pip install chromadb transformers onnxruntime


upgrade chromadb
pip install --upgrade chromadb


add embeddings config
from chromadb.api.models import CollectionCommon
from chromadb.utils.embedding_functions import SentenceTransformerEmbeddingFunction

embedding_function = SentenceTransformerEmbeddingFunction(model_name="all-MiniLM-L6-v2")  # Utilisez un modèle compatible

collection = CollectionCommon(embedding_function=embedding_function)


create the .exe file by telling pyinstaller the missing dependencies
pyinstaller --hidden-import="chromadb.utils.embedding_functions" --hidden-import="transformers" --hidden-import="onnxruntime" UX.py --onefile --noconsole


include chromadb in .spec file
hiddenimports=["chromadb.utils.embedding_functions.onnx_mini_lm_l6_v2"]


checking this post but doesn't resolve it :
chromadb 'ONNXMiniLM_L6_V2' embedding not defined with pyinstaller


